# highcharts not displaying graph

Tags: php, html, mysql, highcharts

im trying to print results stored in my database using php and highcharts api.but the graph doesnt show on the screen.not even the axis get displayed.the data is got from a mysql database.i tries using the same code as in the highcharts demo but no luck.
heres my code

```
<?php
require_once ('connection.php');
session_start();
$username =  $_SESSION['username'];
$quizes=null;
$score=array();
$i=0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `score` WHERE `username`='$username'") or die(mysql_error);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$quizes= $quizes. "'".$rows['quiz']."',";
$score[$i]=$rows['score'];
$i=$i+1;
}
print_r($score);
echo $quizes;
?>
<html>
<body>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
//passing php variables to javascript variables
   //eg  var mk1=<?php echo $mark1 ?>;
 var mk1=<?php echo $score[1] ?>;
 var mk2=<?php echo $score[2] ?>;
 var mk3=<?php echo $score[3] ?>;
 var mk4=<?php echo $score[4] ?>;
 var mk5=<?php echo $score[5] ?>;
 var mk6=<?php echo $score[6] ?>;
 var mk7=<?php echo $score[7] ?>;
 var mk8=<?php echo $score[8] ?>;    
  var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
       renderTo: 'graphDiv',
       defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },
     title: {
       text: 'SEMESTER'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['QUIZ A', 'QUIZ B',  'QUIZ C', 'QUIZ D', 'QUIZ E', 'QUIZ F','QUIZ G','QUIZ  H']
    },
    yAxis: {
       title: {
          text: 'Percentage'
      }
    },
    series: [{
       name: ['Quiz Progress'],
       data: [mk1, mk2, mk3, mk4, mk5, mk6, mk7, mk8]
    },]
   });
 });
 </script>
 <div id="graphDiv" style="width: 700px; height: 400px; float: left"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example to get data from mysql database in highchart.
Lest start with 
**Index.php**

```
<head>
    <meta name="Gopal Joshi" content="Highchart with Mysql" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Highchart with Mysql Database</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/setup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <div id="sales" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
```

**setup.js**

```
var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var cursan = {
   chart: {
    renderTo: 'sales',
    defaultSeriesType: 'area',
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 20
   },
   title: {
    text: 'Highchart With Mysql',
   },
   subtitle: {
    text: 'www.spjoshis.blogspot.com',
   },
   xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
   },
   yAxis: {
    title: {
     text: 'Average'
    },
    plotLines: [{
     value: 0,
     width: 1,
     color: '#808080'
    }]
   },
   tooltip: {
       crosshairs: true,
                shared: true
   },
   legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -10,
    y: 30,
    borderWidth: 0
   },

            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',  
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            },

         series: [{
       color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
    name: 'Test Colomn',
                marker: {
                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    lineColor: null // inherit from series
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: '#666666',
                    align: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: -10,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '9px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        textShadow: '0 0 0px black'
                    }
                }
   }],
        }

        //Fetch MySql Records
        jQuery.get('js/data.php', null, function(tsv) {
   var lines = [];
   traffic = [];
   try {
    // split the data return into lines and parse them
    tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
    jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
     line = line.split(/\t/);
     date = line[0] ;
                                        amo=parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ''));
                                        if (isNaN(amo)) {
                                                   amo = null;
                                        }
     traffic.push([
      date,
      amo
     ]);
    });
   } catch (e) {  }
   cursan.series[0].data = traffic;
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(cursan);
  });
 });
```

Here js will import data from mysql using `data.php` file and supply it to our chart

**data.php**

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$result=mysql_query('select * from sales order by id');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['month'] . "\t" . $row['amount']. "\n";
}
```

`data.php` will simply print value on page that we will use for chart.
You can use this method with multiple charts on same page and no more files will required for more then single chart.

It will output like [image]

[Click Here](http://www.spjoshis.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-table.html) for more help or Download example.

Answer (score 0):

I think your getting data in string format. convert data to integer like this way,

```
var mk1=<?php echo $score[1] ?>;

to integer: +mk1 // and check typeof +mk1
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/XF293/

Answer (score 0):

I advice to consider use json_encode() in php and return all values as single array. Then use $.getJSON() to avoid problems with printing values. As a result how your data looks like? I mean in javascript.